# How can I load Xml generated from Php into an Xforms form for editing?

Tags: php, mysql, xforms, orbeon

I have an application designed using Xforms/Php/Mysql. I have manged to generate Xml from mysql db using Php but how do I load the values of the xml to my xforms form for editing?Also how can I trigger an output control to display an error message when required controls are not filled, assuming i dont want the pop up message element to show in the xforms-submit-error event for submission. Please help and thanks.

Comment: Is this a form you created with Form Builder, or are you writing XForms "by hand" with a text editor?

Comment: Hi Avernet, I am writing the xforms codes 'by hand' with a text editor. Do you have any idea on how to go about this, your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, make a resource using PHP that outputs the XML.  Make it do this when you do HTTP GET.
Then, make it accept back the same XML as an HTTP POST using the this tip from IBM: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xformstipphp/

Let's say your data looks like this:

```
<data>
  <pizza>
    <size>medium</size>
    <topping>pepperoni</topping>
    <notes>Extra cheese</notes>
  </pizza>
</data>
```

This data will be loaded into an XForms "instance" which is what XForms calls XML variables you can load over HTTP and POST back.  When you press Order, the form will post the XML back to your resource, which your PHP should then write back to your database.  The PHP then outputs the updated XML, which is sent back to the XForms processor and it updates the instance and the form displays the updated values, while staying on the same page.

Then, use it like this in your HTML page:

```
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
  <head>
    <title>Pizza</title>
    <model xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
      <instance resource="/path/to/my/data.php" />
      <submission resource="/path/to/my/data.php" method="post" replace="instance" id="order" />
    </model>
  </head>
  <body>
    <group ref="pizza" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
      <select1 ref="size">
        <label>Size: </label>
        <item><label>Large</label><value>large</value></item>
        <item><label>Medium</label><value>medium</value></item>
        <item><label>Small</label><value>small</value></item>
      </select1>
      <select1 ref="topping">
         <label>Topping: </label>
         <item><label>Large</label><value>large</value></item>
         <item><label>Medium</label><value>medium</value></item>
         <item><label>Small</label><value>small</value></item>
      </select1>
      <textarea ref="notes">
         <label>Notes: </label>
      </textarea>
      <submit submission="order">
         <label>Order</label>
      </submit>
    </group>
  </body>
/html
```

This won't look very good if you display it on the page because there's no CSS for layout.
If you're using Orbeon, avernet can help you lay it out.

If you're using AgenceXML xsltforms, put this into block-form.css and add
  
in the head of your page.

```
.block-form {
  margin-left: 3pt;
  margin-top: 3pt;
  margin-bottom: 3pt;

}

.block-form span.xforms-control > span {
  display:inline-block; 
  white-space:nowrap; 
}

.block-form label.xforms-label {
   display:inline-block; width:6em; 
   text-align:left; 
   margin-right:4px;
}

.block-form span.xforms-input.row,
 span.xforms-select.row,
 span.xforms-select1.row,
 span.xforms-textarea.row,
 span.xforms-secret.row,
 span.xforms-output.row {
  display:block;
}

.block-form-section > div.xforms-group-content {
  padding-bottom: 10px; 
  margin: 2px; 
  width: 32em;
}

.block-form-section .xforms-group-label {
  display: inline-block; 
}

.wide .xforms-value { 
  width: 32em;
}
```

Then put class="block-form" on your outer group and class="row" on each of the select1 and textarea and submit.

If you want to see this example working with XSLTForms visit http://xformstest.org/klotz/2011/08/pizza/pizza.xml -- view source will work there as well.  The Order button just submits the data and gets it back unchanged as the PHP program simply ignores it.

If you instead want to go to another page after you get the new data, you can do it like this:

```
<submission resource="/path/to/my/data.php" method="post" replace="instance" id="order">
  <load ev:event="xforms-submit-done" resource="/path/to/my/new/page.html" />
</submission>
```

(To read more about load, see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Load  -- you can have the new page to go to returned as part of the XML instance and use <load if="..." > to conditionally go to another page as well.)

You can also pull the list of toppings out of the HTML page and put it in a second instance, so it can be determined by a separate server-side PHP program or static file.  Read about select1 and itemset to see how to do this.  At that point, you can also begin to use bind to attach conditions to the data, so you can control relevance and make it so that whole wheat pizza can't have bacon, or whatever conditions you can express around the instance data.

**Update**
Here's a running version.  Pressing save POSTs the data but the server side doesn't do anything with it.  Use View Source to see what's going on.  http://xformstest.org/klotz/2011/08/pizza/pizza.xml

Comment: Hi, I now have a php that creates the xml and I want to know if am on the right track. This script creates an xml with data from the database, but how do I post this xml back to the form as new instance data so the form is populated for editing?

Comment: @dush, first you want to have an `<xforms:submission id="get-initial-data" resource="http://path to your service" method="get" ref="instance('my-instance')" serialization="none"/>`. Second, run it when the page load by placing the following in your model: `<xforms:send submission="get-initial-data"/>`.

Comment: <instance id="my-instance" resource="http://path to your service" /> will load the instance when the page loads. separating it into submission and send as avernet suggests might be necessary for more advanced cases, but not for loading the initial data.